# Android java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache directory

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app with access to Dropbox.
Get the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14800): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache directory: /data/data/de.testdbxapp.api/app_DropboxSyncCache
```

Error occured in this line:

```
mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
```

APP_KEY and APP_SECRET should be correct. Generated from Dropbox.
My App has folowing permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I don't use the emulator. Error occured on my Android device. When I delete the line `(mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager...)` the app started correct. But I need the line for Dropbox.

I'm using Android 2.1. (Can't update.) 
Any ideas?

Thx in advance.

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.testdbxapp.api"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="de.testdbxapp.api.TestdbxActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="scheme deleted"/> 

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Dropbox Sync" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/setup#android

can you post your manifest?

Comment: R u running in emulator or phone

Comment: May be wrong any way check it...If u r running this in phone ,its accessing data/data/.. Needs root access.

Comment: @Arju: thx for the tip but I don't need root access. Had problems with the package name in the manifest and the real packagename. Changed the name, delete the generated code and clean/build solved it.